# (mysql) subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch the total .of "jml_pddk_miskin" in each district("kecamatan") with Ascending order. But I get the error as "subquery returns more than one row".

this is my query:

```
select 
mkec.id AS id,mkec.nama AS kecamatan,rpb.tahun AS tahun,
ifnull((select sum(rpb.jml_pddk_miskin) 
        from rekap_penduduk_bps rpb 
        join master_kelurahan mkel on mkel.id = rpb.id_kelurahan 
        where 
        mkel.id_kecamatan = mkec.id 
        and rpb.id_kelurahan = mkel.id 
        group by rpb.id ),0) AS total_miskin 
from master_kecamatan mkec 
join rekap_penduduk_bps rpb 
group by mkec.nama 
order by mkec.id
```

This is the result of above query:
[result query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deXmgH.png)

I want result like this...
[result query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ1za.jpg)

Comment: can you update the schema in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/..

Comment: Bigger query missed `ON` clause

Comment: #justin, can you help me for solving that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
   SELECT mkec.id AS id,mkec.nama AS kecamatan,rpb.tahun AS tahun,IFNULL((SELECT SUM(rpb.jml_pddk_miskin) 
FROM (rekap_penduduk_bps rpb JOIN master_kelurahan mkel ON mkel.id = rpb.id_kelurahan) WHERE 
mkel.id_kecamatan = mkec.id AND rpb.id_kelurahan = mkel.id GROUP BY rpb.id HAVING rpb.id_kelurahan = mkel.id ),0)
 AS total_miskin FROM master_kecamatan mkec JOIN rekap_penduduk_bps rpb ON mkec.id= rpb.id_kelurahan GROUP BY mkec.nama ORDER BY mkec.id
```

Comment: this is the result "Unknown column 'mkel.id' in 'having clause'" :(

Comment: @gierg update your table structure then it will easy for us to give the correct result

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query

```
select sum(rpb.jml_pddk_miskin) 
from rekap_penduduk_bps rpb 
join master_kelurahan mkel on mkel.id = rpb.id_kelurahan 
where 
mkel.id_kecamatan = mkec.id 
and rpb.id_kelurahan = mkel.id 
group by rpb.id
```

is obviously returning more than one row (by the `group by` clause).

Comment: how to fix that query.. :(

Comment: rpb.id is id of "rekap_penduduk_bps" table. in that tables there are foreign key from table "master_kelurahan, and master_kecamatan having id in table master_kelurahan.